# Unable to run setup:upgrade command- Scandipwa

Tags: reactjs, magento2, progressive-web-apps, varnish, magento2.4

Installing scandipwa after cache changes to varinsh cache.
I'm Facing an error while running setup:upgrade command.

`Error flushing Varnish server. Host: "scandi.pwa". PURGE response code: 500 message: Internal Server Error`

using apache. Can we fix this on apache without using nginx?

Thanks

Comment: Please add your full VCL file to your question as well as the output of the following command: `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'"`. This will help me understand what's going on behind the scenes.